# How to find all objects in a layer which intersect or are contained by a polygon object?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am writing a web app in Javascript using the Mapbox GL JS.
I have a layer of polygons. The user can create a target polygon in the app (not in Mapbox layer).
I need to find all polygons in the Mapbox layer which are either fully contained by or which intersect the target polygon.

Does anyone have an example of how to find all polygon objects in a Mapbox layer which either intersect, or are fully contained by, a specified polygon object?

I have tried using this example from the Mapbox documentation but it only works with a bounding rectangle [Highlight features within a bounding box](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/using-box-queryrenderedfeatures/) I have looked at several questions in StackExchange related to the queryRenderedFeatures function but none solve my issue. Here is pseudocode for what I am after:

```
var targetPolygon = {*GEOJSON Polygon object*}
var intersection = map.FindOverlappingObjects(targetPolygon, 'MapLayer')
for each obj in intersection { 
  console.log("Name: ", obj.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Turf's `booleanIntersects` for this: http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanIntersects